# Query to get time count from mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my data in mongodb database as

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5319acf0b06f6e98371ca505"),
   "field1": "",
   "date": "07-03-2014",
   "os": "android",
   "time": "11:26:40",
   "userid": "xxxx"
}
```

I wanted to get count of all records having time from 00 to 23.
I have written my query as

```
$time_start = date('00');
$time_end = date('23');
$keys = array("time" => 1);
$initial = array("counttime" => array());
$reduce = "function(obj, prev) {
    if (obj.time != null) 
        if (obj.time instanceof Array) prev.counttime += obj.time.length;
        else prev.counttime++;  }";     
$condition = array(
    'condition' => array(
        "time" => array(
            '$gt' => $time_start,
            '$lte' => $time_end 
        )
     )
);

$g = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce , $condition);`
```

I have tried to get hour but thats not working for me.
I have used as

```
$condition = array(
    'condition' => array(
        "HOUR(time)" => array(
            '$gt' => $time_start,'$lte' => $time_end)
        )
);
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: @joao. Can you please tell me how mongodb aggregation framework works for date if i change field property?

Comment: If you change your date/time properties from string to date it is pretty easy to do it using the mongodb aggregation framework.

Comment: Why are people using strings as dates? String is a string, nevertheless it looks like a date.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), which you really should favor over [`.group()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) in any case, as it uses native code rather than JavaScript for it's results:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match one date (tell you later)
    { "$match": { "date": "07-03-2014" } },

    // Project the hour
    { "$project": {
        "hour": { "$substr": [ "$time", 0, 2 ] }
    }},

    // Group on the hour
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$hour",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Now this relies on that you have your "time" stored as a string. So you `$project` the "hour" part of that "time" and then `$group` on it, keeping a count of records found.

I restricted this to one "date" because as with "time" this is also a string. Depending on what you want to do you can possibly get unexpected results from this, so generally speaking, using "strings" for date representation is not a good idea.

If you just had a proper BSON date in a field called "timestamp" then you can do things like this, where you can even set ranges:

```js
var start_date = new Date("2014-02-01");
var end_date = new Date("2014-03-01");

db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match on the date range
    { "$match": { "timestamp": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date } },

    // Project day and hour
    { "$project": {
        "day": {
            "year": { "$year": "$timestamp" },
            "month": { "$month": "$timestamp" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$timestamp" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$timestamp" }
        }
    }},

    // Group on the day
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$day",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

But with your present date format, ranges are going to be a problem. So best to convert where you can.

Comment: db.collection.aggregate is not working properly with me.I have tried this but it was creating issue that’s why i have used group option.

Comment: @ArpiPatel From the **first** sample above and your document as it is this will correctly pick out the the value of "11" and count it once. It also works because it is taking out "just" the hour so that everything in that "hour" is counted. So that will work, but anything else is likely to fail unless you use **real** dates